# Eevee shadows and lighting in viewport different from final results

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, lighting, shadows, hdri

I've always used cycles engine in blender 2.79 but when 2.8 was released I tried to switch to eevee since it take less time to render and it looks good
but the problem with eevee is the lighting looks very good in the viewport but when rendering the scene the shadows looks off and not like in the viewport.

Viewport :

[image]

Render result :

[image]

I thought that there was a problem with the HDRI since it casts light as well but when I turned strength to 0 the render results were the same.

- **Blender version** - *2.83.1*
- **Render engine** - *Eevee*

Comment: Have you baked the indirect lighting?

Comment: Yes,but the results are the same

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out the Sun's interactive point doesn't change place in final render result when I move it so I have to rotate the main sun